# For what reasons shall a kings residence be outside the city ?

Tags: kingdom

I plan on the kings having a residence right outside the city. Does it really work?

Comment: Versailles. Castel Gandolfo  Windsor Castle. Seems well established.

Comment: I apologize, but to avoid closure for either "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based" you need to provide restrictions, conditions, and description that allows a definitive answer to be given.  Please review our [tour] and [help] for details.

Answer (score 2):

Short form. .. yes.

Medieval: cities are unhygienic and smelly. The king had power and means to build a fortress residence outside the city

Renaissance : Same as medieval,  but the nation's are wealthier and times are less warlike. The palace is less fortress like,  and more comfortable.  It may even have indoor plumbing and flush toilets.

Modern and future: the countryside is where you want to live, if you have the means you get away from the paparazzi and have room for your kids to be kids.  There is no advantage to living in a city.

Comment: "One man's meat is another man's poison".  Once a week I would take the train from the suburb where I lived to the big city to visit the central public library and the university libraries.  The central public library was like my home away from home.  So I can agree with countless millions of people who live in big cities - or wish that they did - and say that countless millions of people think that there is no advantage to living outside of a city.

Comment: And every famous medieval kingdom had one or more royal residences in the capital city.  London, England had Westminster Palace and the Tower of London,  Paris, France had the palace of the Ille de la City, the Louvre, the Hotel de Tournelles, etc.  Above all, Constantinople had The Great Palace and the Blachernae Palace, etc., inside the walls as well as suburban palaces outside the walls.

Comment: @M. A. Golding: If you're a king (or even reasonably wealthy), you can afford to have a library in your castle.  If other libraries have books you want, you just order your servants to fetch them.  (And these days even ordinary folks can order our electronic servants to do that :-))  As for king's residences within the city, you're neglecting the importance of communication time: when horses are the fastest means of communication, the ruler will at times need to stay near the seat of government to issue timely orders &c.

Comment: @jamesqf when horses were the fastest means of communication, kings traveled with much of the government in tow. That's why they had palaces for residences - it was much more than an ego building exercise.

Comment: A missing reason: security. A residence within a city is well within reach of a revolting populace; a remote one far less. And in the worst case, you are likely to have advance warning of the enemy incoming and have a escape path, which can be difficult inside a city.

Answer (score 0):

It can, of course. Most monarchs have / have had multiple residences both inside and outside their capital cities. The Queen has Balmoral Castle, for example, and so far the English haven't risen up in riot just because she's not in London! As mentioned, the Pope of Rome has Castel Gandolfo. The Spanish monarch has residences in Madrid, Segovia & Palma de Mallorca.

I suspect, however, that you're leaning towards a situation where the monarch *never* lives inside the City, is that right? It will work best if you come up with some curious historical reason for this. Perhaps, long ago, the king needed to live near his army's barracks so that he could jump out and lead them to war at a moment's notice. Anymore, with a modern army and airforce under immediate command of field and air marshals, the logistical reasons no longer exist. But because it's been that way for something like 843 years, no one has ever thought to change things up.

Probably some system of rapid underground transport will be in place to whisk the monarch to Parliament House or the Ministry of Defense's Bunker at need.